# Flutter Nested Widget Callback/Async Questions

Tags: dart, flutter

From a [Flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12528) posted by [Yueh Chou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8576045/yueh-chou):

> Not sure if the event will bubble up to the parent widget and trigger
>   the animation with all the nested widgets and callbacks.
>
> In the Original files,
>
> Pressing on a grandchild widget(e.g. FlatButton) of a BackWidget it
>   will trigger a ModalDialog call and pressing the button will make an
>   async call. The Flip Effect will take place at the end of a successful
>   async call.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      home: new Container(color: Colors.white, child: new RootWidget())));
}

class RootWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  FlipWidget mainFlipWidget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    mainFlipWidget = new FlipWidget(
      frontWidget: frontWidget,
      backWidget: new BackWidget(
        onPressedButton: () {
          _flipMainButton();
        },
      ),
    );
    return new Center(child:mainFlipWidget);
  }

  _flipMainButton() {
    mainFlipWidget.doTheFlip();
  }
}

class BackWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  BackWidget({
    this.onPressedButton,
  });

  final VoidCallback onPressedButton;
   Widget buttonFlipWidget;
  _BackWidgetState createState() => new _BackWidgetState();
}

class _BackWidgetState extends State<BackWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widget.buttonFlipWidget = new Container(
      height: 180.0,
      color: Colors.grey[200],
      child:new FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          triggerCb();
        },
        child: new Text('Press me'),
      ),
    );
    return widget.buttonFlipWidget;
  }

  triggerCb() {
      widget.onPressedButton();
  }
}

class FlipWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  FlipWidget({
    @required this.frontWidget,
    @required this.backWidget,
  });

  final Widget frontWidget;
  final Widget backWidget;
  final _FlipWidgetState _state = new _FlipWidgetState();

  doTheFlip () {
    _state.doTheFlip();
  }

  _FlipWidgetState createState() => _state;
}

class _FlipWidgetState extends State<FlipWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _frontScale;
  Animation<double> _backScale;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),);
    _frontScale = new Tween(
      begin: 1.0,
      end: 0.0,
    ).animate(new CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: new Interval(0.0, 0.5, curve: Curves.easeIn),
    ));
    _backScale = new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: new Interval(0.5, 1.0, curve: Curves.easeOut),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Stack(
          children: [
            new AnimatedBuilder(
              child: widget.frontWidget,
              animation: _backScale,
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                final Matrix4 transform = new Matrix4.identity()
                  ..scale(_backScale.value, 1.0, 1.0);

                return new Transform(
                  transform: transform,
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            ),
            new AnimatedBuilder(
                child: widget.backWidget,
                animation: _frontScale,
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  final Matrix4 transform = new Matrix4.identity()
                    ..scale(_frontScale.value, 1.0, 1.0);
                  return new Transform(
                    transform: transform,
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    child: child,
                  );
                }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  doTheFlip() {
    setState(() {
      if (_controller.isCompleted || _controller.velocity > 0)
        _controller.reverse();
      else
        _controller.forward();
    });
  }
}

final Widget frontWidget = new Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  height: 180.0,
  child: new Column(
    children: [
      new Text("Front Side of the card")
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 9):

Some changes you should make to this code.

- `RootWidget` should be stateful. Store the `flipped` state there.
- `BackWidget` should be stateless. All it has to do is notify `RootWidget` that the button was pressed.
- `FlipWidget` should detect changes to `flipped` using `didUpdateWidget`.
- Don't store a `State` into a member variable of a `Widget`, and avoid putting mutator methods on your `State` if you can avoid it... this is often a sign that you need to store the state higher in your widget tree and pass it down with constructor arguments.

Learn more about `StatefulWidget` and `StatelessWidget` in the [Widget Framework Tour](https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/) and [interactivity tutorial](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/).

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new RootWidget(),
    ),
  ));
}

class RootWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RootWidgetState createState() => new _RootWidgetState();
}

class _RootWidgetState extends State<RootWidget> {
  bool _flipped = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new FlipWidget(
        flipped: _flipped,
        frontWidget: new Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: 180.0,
          child: new Column(
            children: [
              new Text("Front Side of the card")
            ],
          ),
        ),
        backWidget: new BackWidget(
          onPressedButton: () {
            setState(() {
              _flipped = !_flipped;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BackWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  BackWidget({
    this.onPressedButton,
  });
  final VoidCallback onPressedButton;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      height: 180.0,
      color: Colors.grey[200],
      child:new FlatButton(
        onPressed: onPressedButton,
        child: new Text('Press me'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FlipWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  FlipWidget({
    @required this.frontWidget,
    @required this.backWidget,
    @required this.flipped,
  });

  final Widget frontWidget;
  final Widget backWidget;
  final bool flipped;

  @override
  _FlipWidgetState createState() => new _FlipWidgetState();
}

class _FlipWidgetState extends State<FlipWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _frontScale;
  Animation<double> _backScale;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500)
    )..value = widget.flipped ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    _frontScale = new Tween(
      begin: 1.0,
      end: 0.0,
    ).animate(new CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: new Interval(0.0, 0.5, curve: Curves.easeIn),
    ));
    _backScale = new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: new Interval(0.5, 1.0, curve: Curves.easeOut),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(FlipWidget oldWidget) {
    if (widget.flipped != oldWidget.flipped) {
      if (widget.flipped) {
        _controller.forward();
      } else {
        _controller.reverse();
      }
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Stack(
          children: [
            new AnimatedBuilder(
              child: widget.frontWidget,
              animation: _backScale,
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                final Matrix4 transform = new Matrix4.identity()
                  ..scale(_backScale.value, 1.0, 1.0);

                return new Transform(
                  transform: transform,
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            ),
            new AnimatedBuilder(
                child: widget.backWidget,
                animation: _frontScale,
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  final Matrix4 transform = new Matrix4.identity()
                    ..scale(_frontScale.value, 1.0, 1.0);
                  return new Transform(
                    transform: transform,
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    child: child,
                  );
                }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```